# Best way to prevent XSS hacking with (embedded)user generated json?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, xss

See i.e.: http://jsfiddle.net/agv9ya39/

```
var json = { name: "</script><script>alert(123);</script>" };
```

Note that I **do** want to embed the json in the page (data is closely related to the page, can't be cached and I don't want to do an extra request)

One solution would be doing a `String.Replace("</script>`) on the whole json string before outputting. But it feels hacky, and I'm probably missing other cases vulnerable for XSS.

Of course I can also make sure it nevers ends up like this in the database, but I rather have an extra protection for if something slips in anyway.

I am using C# and Json.Net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `<!--` and `</script>` with `<\!--` and `<\/script>` to cover all `<script>` break-outs for JSON. Consider putting the JSON in a `data-*` attribute instead, though, and reading it with `JSON.parse`.

```html
<div id="some-relevant-element"
     data-json="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;</script><script>alert(123);</script>&quot;}">
   …
</div>

<script>
var someRelevantElement = document.getElementById('some-relevant-element');
var json = JSON.parse(someRelevantElement.getAttribute('data-json'));
</script>
```

Comment: Note that when you put it in a `data-` attribute, you must HTML-attribute-escape it.

Comment: I;m pretty sure escaping `/` is enough if you are inside a script tag (since the only problematic string is `</string>`)

Comment: Hi @minitech, nice solution. I would be a bit worried about the length of the data attribute though. I'm actually reading all the data from the page from json - if there are some big pieces of text in there..

Comment: Hi @minitech, I actually notice that <\/script> is actually automatically converted on the client side: do you know where I can find more information about this type of escaping?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: No, there’s an unlikely but still possible exploit where a `<!--<script>` sequence will cause the legitimate `</script>` to be considered part of the script. I’ll find an example at some point.

Comment: @DirkBoer: Any backslash followed by a character that doesn’t make a valid escape sequence is ignored, e.g. `"\z" === "z"`.