# Pass object variable from server to client in Pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I know that I can pass variables form the server through the template like this:

```
//- template.pug
p #{name}'s Pug source code!
```

and calling as such

```
pug.renderFile('template.pug', {
  name: 'Timothy'
})
```

(literally copy/pasted from [their landing page](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html)

But I would like to pass "more complex" variables, for example my pug source may have within it

```
script.
  window.foo = !{foo};
```

and I want to pass the list of objects:

```
foo = [{one: 1}, {two: 2}, {three: 3}];
pug.renderFile('template.pug', { foo });
```

but this produces

```
<script>
window.foo = [[Object object], [Object object
```

and so on. Looks like pug (or something in the pipeline) calls "toString" on the input.

I tried to fix it using JSON stringification as [Kyle Gillen helpfully answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50302447/3310334), so I wrote this:

```
script.
  window.foo = JSON.parse('!{JSON.stringify(foo)}');
```

But my `foo` variable actually contains lots of `'` single-apostrophe characters, so this errors too. And wrapping in `"` double quotes is annoying because `JSON.stringify` produces JSON with double quotes of course.

I have tried escaping every `'` like

```
script.
  window.foo = JSON.parse('!{JSON.stringify(foo).replace(/'/, "\\'")}');
```

But this has been inconsistent. I think there are other characters or weirdness within the stringification that makes the string end early, I've been getting different errors every time I iteratively try to correct previous ones.

That's why I thought to ask this question, because I'm sure there must be a simpler and better way to do this.

How can I safely pass exactly the same variable from my server to my client through pug?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32657540/best-way-to-prevent-xss-hacking-with-embeddeduser-generated-json/32657615#32657615. If you don’t fully understand what the issue is, I recommend the attribute version, e.g. `script(id='foo', data-foo=JSON.stringify(foo))`.